# Why does intelliJ not choose the latest version .xsd file?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, xsd

I have 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd' in my schemaLocation list.

Examining the jar file for the 3.1.0.RELEASE of spring-security I see there are several older versions of the schema included as seen below.

[image: maven pulled down this jar for spring-security]

So I figured intelliJ must be using the 3.1.xsd because I specified that in my pom and in my schemaLocation list.

But, as you can see below, it's deciding to use the 3.0 xsd, why is this?

[image: path to xsd file that intelliJ uses]

EDIT NOTE : please just CTRL or COMMAND and '+' to zoom in to see the second image, sorry!